# How to: change html code to method values?

Tags: c#, html

I wrote a really simple class in c# class library (.dll). This code creates a html file and return it to a string.
In place of: `<p>NUMBER</p>` I want to change it and add int number from this method.

```
    public class Class1
{
    public string HTMLTable(int number)
    {
        string html = "<p>NUMBER</p>";

        var xDocument = new XDocument(
            new XDocumentType("html", null, null, null),
            new XElement("html",
                new XElement("head"),
                new XElement("body",
                        XElement.Parse(html))
                    )
                )
           )
        );

        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "\t"
        };

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
            {
                xDocument.WriteTo(writer);
            }

            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Important to realize is that `html` is just a string, it is _not_ html. So your question is how to replace part of a string by something else, or, how to define that string including a parameter.

Comment: okay, but it is very important for me to generate html

Comment: I'm just saying that your replacement can be done on a string, as @AdamBrown's answer shows. You don't need to replace anything in your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string interpolation.

```
var html = $"<p>{number}</p>";
```

UPDATE: Or as suggested for people not wanting to use the much better string interpolation, you can do this:

```
var html = string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that;

```
string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", number);
```

Also, I suggest you to use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse and process HTML. It is a very powerful library. You can find it on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have more as one part to change, a good choice is the [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine)

```
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating; // For extension methods.

var template = "<html><body>Hello @Model.Number, welcome to RazorEngine!</body></html>";
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, new { Number = 10 });
```

**nuget**

```
PM> Install-Package RazorEngine -Version 3.10.0
```